# JQuery Datatables/Bootstrap files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, bootstrap-4

Fairly new to Bootstrap and have a pretty general question.  I'm working on a .NET MVC application and started with the generic MVC template.  The project already has the Bootstrap files in place, the .css file in the Content folder and the .js file in the Scripts folder.  I'm also trying to implement jQuery Datatables in the project and I downloaded Bootstrap 4 along with it.  It comes down in it's own folder "Bootstrap-4-4.0.0", which has child js and css folders, which I placed in the Scripts folder of my project.  My main question is, if I've downloaded Bootstrap with Datatables, do I have to ignore/remove the bootstrap files that were already in the project template (pointing to the .css file in the content folder and the .js file in the scripts folder) and just point the bundles to the Bootstrap-4-4.0.0 subfolders?

Comment: You will want only one copy of each CSS  and JS include file.  Either remove what is there or use the [Download Builder](https://datatables.net/download/index) to get Datatables without the Bootstrap files.

Comment: Thank you, this got me where I needed to be.